How to test Google's OAuth granular consent screen for TV & Device Apps
We received a notice from Google "OAuth clients must support granular consent, starting June 17, 2024".
Our apps OAuth Client is TV and Limited-Input Devices.
We tested to display granular conscent OAuth scren using below scopes.
"openid"
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"
However we cannot confirm the granular consent screen, in spite of after June 17.

Does not an OAuth client for TV and Limited-Input Devices support granular consent?
(We are hoping an OAuth client for TV and Limited-Input Devices don't support it.)
If it supports granular consent, we want to know how to display granular consent screen for TV and Limited-Input Devices.


Could you provide more information on the OAuth flow on TV? Do you use the Client ID "TV and Limited Input devices" type?  What OS, language, and SDK are you using for OAuth flow on TV? Is this instruction https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/limited-input-device you followed? If not, what instruction do you follow?

Yes, we use the Client ID "TV and Limited Input devices" type.
Our application is installed on Windows Server 2019 Standard (1809, Build"17763.3046").
The develop lang is C#, and using below SDK
Google.Apis 1.61.0
Google.Apis.Auth 1.61.0
Google.Apis.Core 1.61.0
Google.Apis.Drive.v3 1.61.0.3120
As of today we cannot confirm the granular consent screen.

I just confirmed that the granular permissions rollout would affect "TV and Limited Input devices" clients. The rollout has started and would slowly roll out to all clients. Hence, you may not see the granular permissions consent screen yet. I would suggest you do the following:

If you need more time to update, test, deploy your code to support granular permissions, please follow the steps in the email ("OAuth clients must support granular consent, starting June 17, 2024") you received to request an extension.

Follow "Best practices to handle granular permissions" to update your applications to handle partial consent. The SDKs you mentioned should support that. Essentially, you want to check what kind of scopes users authorized. Before granular permissions rollout, you can assume if users authorized your requests, all the scopes are granted. After the rollout, you can't assume all scopes are granted. Hence, you need to check which scopes are granted and update your application functionalities accordingly.

See "Test your updated application on handling granular permissions" on how to test your application by enabling granular permissions before the rollout.



Thank you  for your reply. We understood it.
May I ask one more question?
Would you happen to know when will the all roll out be done?

When it fully rolls out, users would be able to select which permissions to grant to your app. Using your screenshot (https://i.sstatic.net/KPndm0mG.png) as an example, users could either approve or deny the entire request. That means your app can expect that if users approve the request, your app has permissions to the two scopes (YouTube and Drive).

When granular permissions fully rolls out, users would see checkbox on each scopes (example - https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/resources/granular-permissions#more-than-one-non-sign-in-scope). Hence, your app can't assume when users grant your request, it doesn't necessarily mean both scopes (YouTube and Drive) are granted. Your app has to check which scopes users granted and update the functionalities accordingly.

I'll ask you again. Do you know when OAuth screen will have changed to granular consent by?

The rollout has already started. It is gradually rolling out to all affected clients. However, I don't have a specific timeline. You may want to request an extension if you haven't done so.

Thank you for your reply. I understand. Thank you for your big support.
